# How to not repeat posts on the same page? With WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to display all posts on the main page that will vary. That is, they will not repeat on the same page. I display them using `WP_Query`, but for each column of posts I need to have another 'posts_per_page'. How to do it?

I trying this:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
```

and

```
this <?php  $my_query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
$my_query->query($my_query->query_vars); ?>
```

Here is my code example one:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-12 featured-posts">
                    <?php  $my_query->set('posts_per_page', 3); $my_query->query($my_query->query_vars); ?>
                    <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <article class="post post-id-<?php echo the_ID(); ?>">
                            <a class="post-thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                            <div class="post-content">
                                <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                <?php healthybroom_posted_on(); ?>
                                <?php healthybroom_entry_footer(); ?>
                                <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 front-random-posts">
                    <?php  $my_query->set('posts_per_page', 5); $my_query->query($my_query->query_vars); ?>
                    <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <article class="post post-id-<?php echo the_ID(); ?>">
                            <a class="post-thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                            <div class="post-content">
                                <?php healthybroom_entry_footer(); ?>
                                <h3 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                <?php healthybroom_posted_on(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want the posts to not be repeated simply.

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 loops with random posts and you want to avoid to have same posts in the 2 loops, you can use the following code :

```
<!-- We create an array for saving the IDs of the post displaying in the first loop -->
<?php $store_posts_ids = array(); ?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-12 featured-posts">
        <?php 
            $my_query->set('posts_per_page', 3);      
            $my_query->query($my_query->query_vars); 
        ?>
        <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

             <!-- We store the post id for the second loop -->
             <?php array_push( $store_posts_ids, get_the_ID() ); ?>

             <!-- Your code here -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 front-random-posts">
        <?php 
            /*
            If you want to display 5 posts, you need to have a loop
            of 7 posts because you have 3 posts in your first loop
            */
            $number_post = 0;
            $my_query->set('posts_per_page', 5);      
            $my_query->query($my_query->query_vars); 
        ?>
        <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php array( $store_posts_ids, get_the_ID() ); ?>

             <!-- If we have our 5 posts, no need to display more posts -->
             <?php if( $number_post < 5 ): ?> 

                 <!-- If the post is not in the first loop -->
                 <?php if( !in_array( $store_posts_ids, get_the_ID() ) ): ?>
                     <?php $number_post = $number_post + 1; ?>   

                     <!-- Your code here -->

                 <?php endif; ?>

             <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
     </div>
</div>
```